# Open new window from TableView in Titanium Mobile

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

i create some application in titanium mobile for opening a window when a row in TableView is clicked by user..

here's my code:

Menu.js

```
function Menu() {
    Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

    var masterMenu = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

    var winMenu1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        title:'Menu 1',
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });
    var tabMenu1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
        icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
        title:'Menu 1',
        window:winMenu1
    });

    var menuData1 = [
        {title: 'Account', url: 'Account.js'}, 
        {title: 'Meetings', url: 'Meetings.js'} 
    ];

    var menuList1 = Ti.UI.createTableView({
      data: menuData1
    });

    menuList1.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
        var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
            url:e.rowData.url,
            title:e.rowData.title 
        }); 
        newWindow.open({
            animated:true
        });
    });

    winMenu1.add(menuList1);

    var winMenu2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        title:'Menu 2',
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });
    var tabMenu2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
        icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
        title:'Menu 2',
        window:winMenu2
    });

    masterMenu.addTab(tabMenu1);  
    masterMenu.addTab(tabMenu2);  

    return masterMenu;
}

module.exports = Menu;
```

when some row is clicked by user, it will redirect and open new window based on url on the menuData1. for example i clicked Account row, and it should be redirected to Account.js. Here's my Account.js code :

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color:'#999',
    text:'Close',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'auto'
});

label1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    win.close();
});

win.add(label1);
```

The main problem is label1 in Account.js not opened in new window but shown in menu list.
Does anyone know how to open Account.js in new window?? thanks before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set backgroundColor for your window:

```
menuList1.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        url:e.rowData.url,
        title:e.rowData.title 
    }); 
    newWindow.open({
        animated:true
    });
});
```

Comment: @Ch4rAss Can I ask you something, do I have to close the previous one?